# Logging into web application with microsoft account through JMeter

Tags: authentication, post, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to login into a web application which uses microsoft accounts for authentication. I am using Jmeter for load testing and I was wondering how I could login to the microsoft accounts using Jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "quick and easy" answer because there are many possible ways of implementing what you call "microsoft accounts".

If your application uses [Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/) first of all you need to know what protocol is being used under the hood, which might be:

- [OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
- [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc)
- [SAML 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol)

and the instructions will be different for each of these protocols, in some cases like for [SAML](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) it's just a matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), others are more complex and require some extra effort in order to get the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) token

Comment: I'll look into these, appreciate it!

Comment: The protocol being used is OpenID Connect, upon going to the web application, it opens up a microsoft login page where you enter your email, then submit your password, and then get redirected back to the web application. Do you know how I would simulate this in Jmeter? Thanks